# SBS 2011 Server CPU Utilization

Tags: windows-sbs

First... I have always been under the impression that if CPU Utilization is running a constant 20-30% or higher that you have a problem. I have been told that processes could spike to 80 or even 90% but as long as they drop back to zero really quick it isn't a problem. So what have others heard about when a constant CPU utilization is a problem as far as percent?

We are having some Excel problems and all the spreadsheets are on the server. It is like some sort of speed issue. On the Server the System (NT Kernel & System) process is always bouncing between 5 and 20%. The average being maybe 10%. This is constant. Never goes to zero. Isn't that a problem?

Comment: If your PC is doing something it will naturally use some CPU time. If it’s constantly doing things, it will constantly utilize the CPU. You have a problem if the CPU is overloaded. It clearly isn’t at 30% or even 50%. So instead of asking about your not-so-busy CPU, ask about “some Excel problems”. In (much!) greater detail.

Comment: I agree with Daniel.  Your CPU isn't overloaded until it's tasked with enough work to push it to 100% of its capacity. Until then, whatever problem you are having isn't because of your CPU.

Comment: I am going to take issue with that. It isn't overloaded until it hits 100%? Try doing something on a computer that is running even 60% CPU utilization. See if you can get anything done. It isn't unusual for a process to jump up to mayne 80-90% but it won't stay there. It will almost immediately come back down.The answers that I have been getting are that if a process is running a constant 20-30% that it warrants looking in to. That the constant high CPU usage by a single process is usually a result of another issue.

Comment: I tried posting the problem about Excel and never got a reply but it is a good example. When this problem with Excel arises Excel.exe (in task manager) shoots up to a constant 65% at which point they can't do anything else on their computer until they close Excel. The 65% CPU utilization made the computer unusable.